# How do i know that which menu item is clicked?

Tags: gwt

My code is

```
          VerticalPanel v1 = new VerticalPanel();

    Command comm = new Command() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
                       // How i know that which menu item is cliked
        }
    };

    MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();
    menu.setWidth("500px");
    menu.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    menu.setAutoOpen(true);
    menu.addSeparator();
    MenuBar fileBar = new MenuBar(true);
    MenuBar editBar = new MenuBar(true);

    fileBar.addItem(new MenuItem("New", comm));
    fileBar.addSeparator();
    fileBar.addItem(new MenuItem("Open", comm));
    fileBar.addItem(new MenuItem("Save", comm));

    editBar.addItem("Edit 11", comm);
    editBar.addItem("Edit 11", comm);

    menu.addItem(new MenuItem("File", fileBar));
    menu.addItem(new MenuItem("Edit", editBar));

    v1.add(menu);
```

please help me

Comment: In GWT there is no option to add listener to menu ....

can u tell me the exact code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesn't seem to be something you get out of the box. But you can use on of the following options:

1. In `MenuBar` there is a protected method `getSelectedItem()`, this returns the `MenuItem` which should match the one clicked. I don't know why it's protected, but by extending the `MenuBar` class and make it public you should be able to use it.
2. You can create a `Command` class, where you inject the `MenuItem` upon creation, in that case you need to set the command after creation and not in the constructor of the `MenuItem`

Command implementation:

```
public class MyCommand implements Command {

  private final MenuItem item;

  public MyCommand(MenuItem item) {
    this.item = item;
  }

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    //item matches the item clicked.
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem("New", (Command)null);
newItem.setCommand(new MyCommand(newItem));
```

Or instead of passing the `MenuItem` via the `MyCommand` constructor add a method to the `MyCommand` class named `setMenuItem`:

```
MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem("New", new MyCommand());
((MyCommand)newItem.getCommand()).setMenuItem(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get answer

```
    Command comm1 = new Command() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            Window.alert("New item is clicked");
        }
    };

    Command comm2 = new Command() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            Window.alert("Open item is clicked");
        }
    };

                fileBar.addItem(new MenuItem("New", comm1));

                fileBar.addItem(new MenuItem("Open", comm2));
```

but we have to create separate object for that ...

but i don't think that this is perfect solution , but it work 100%