# How to wire up GWT hyperlink click handler?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I am brand new to GWT and am trying to achieve the following:

[image]

Here's the code that I've cooked up:

```
public class MyWebApp implements EntryPoint {
    // The main container for everything the user sees (the "view")
    private LayoutPanel mainPanel;

    // Simple HTML for the header ("MyWebApp") and subsequent <hr/>
    private SafeHtml header;

    // The three links "Dashboard", "Monitors" and "Help Desk"
    private HorizontalPanel navMenu;

    // The empty content that gets populated when user clicks one of
    // the 3 links.
    private Panel menuContent;

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // The initial fragment contains the header, nav menu and empty "content" div.
        // Each menu/screen then fills out content div.
        initMainPanel();

        RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);
    }

    private void initMainPanel() {
        SafeHtmlBuilder headerBuilder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        navMenu = new HorizontalPanel();

        // Leaving null until user clicks on one of the 3 menus.
        // Then the menu will decide what panel gets injected for
        // this panel.
        menuContent = null;

        // Create the simple HTML for the header.
        headerBuilder.append("<h1>MyWebApp</h1><hr/>");

        // Create the navMenu items.
        Hyperlink dashboardLink, monitorsLink, helpDeskLink;

        // Homepage is http://www.mywebapp.com
        // I want the dashboardLink to inject menuContent and "redirect" user to
        // http://www.mywebapp.com/dashboard
        dashboardLink = new Hyperlink("???", "???");

        // http://www.mywebapp.com/monitors
        monitorsLink = new Hyperlink("???", "???");

        // http://www.mywebapp.com/help-desk
        helpDeskLink = new Hyperlink("???", "???");
        navMenu.add(dashboardLink);
        navMenu.add(monitorsLink);
        navMenu.add(helpDeskLink);

        // Add all widgets to the mainPanel.
        mainPanel.add(new HTML(headerBuilder.toSafeHtml().toString()));
        mainPanel.add(navMenu);
        mainPanel.add(menuContent);

        // Position and size the widgets (omitted for brevity).
        // mainPanel.setWidgetHorizontalPosition(...);
    }

    private HTML getDashboardMenuContent() {
        return new HTML("This is the dashboard.");
    }

    private HTML getMonitorsMenuContent() {
        return new HTML("These are the monitors.");
    }

    private HTML getHelpDeskMenuContent() {
        return new HTML("This is the help desk.");
    }
}
```

Most importantly:

- How do I "wire up" the `Hyperlink`s so that when the user clicks them, I can call the appropriate `getXXXMenuContent()` method, and then add that to `menuContent`?

But also:

- I *feel* like I'm doing something wrong here: `mainPanel.add(new HTML(headerBuilder.toSafeHtml().toString()));` - if so what is it?!? How should I be adding a simple `<h1>` and `<hr/>` in a way that's secure (hence the use of the Safe* objects), efficient, and conforming to recommended practices?
- Should I be implementing `UiBinder` here? If so, would I make `UiBinder`s for each menu's content or for the entire `mainPanel`, or both?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
dashboardLink.addClickHandler( 
   new ClickHandler() 
   {
       public void onClick( ClickEvent event ) 
       {
           mainPanel.setWidget( getDashboardMenuContent() );
       }
   } );
```

You should note that `Hyperlink.addClickHandler(...)` is deprecated and it is recommended to use `Anchor.addClickHandler(...)` instead.

As for the other questions: It is a lot more elegant and easier to build UI's with UIBinder, so definitely look into that, but do try to make "it" work first to avoid the added complexity of the `.ui.xml` setup :-)

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks @Anders Rostgaard Bystru (+1) - and I *especially*  appreciate the code sample (helps me visualize it)! One quick followup regarding the UiBinder: I understand that its a matter of preference whether to use it or not. I guess I'm struggling to *visualize* how a UiBinder could be used here. I'm not sure if I should have individual UiBinder snippets (XMLs?) for each Widgets (the H1 and H$ tags, the 3 menus, the menuContent panel) or just 1 big one for the whole "page". Thanks again!

Comment: No prob. Again that's a matter of opinion :-) For relatively simple pages I'd recommend one UiBinder and use `Panel`'s within that to place your widgets. Once you progress to more complex setups, you could easily have UIBinder's within panels contained in parent UIBinders.

Comment: I also recommend using the UI Binders. It really does remove a ton of boilerplate code. Give it a shot ;)

Answer (score 2):

`Hyperlink` widgets trigger *navigation*. You don't want to handle clicks on them, you want to handle navigation (that could be triggered by clicking a `Hyperlink` or using the browser's back/forward buttons, a bookmark or link from elsewhere –including Ctrl+clicking a `Hyperlink` to open it in a new window/tab–, etc.)

To react to those navigation events, use `History.addValueChangeHandler`; and to handle the *initial navigation* on application start, call `History.fireCurrentHistoryState()` (after you add your handler of course).

More details in: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory

---

Would be better to split other questions to... other questions, but here are the answers anyway:

> I feel like I'm doing something wrong here: `mainPanel.add(new HTML(headerBuilder.toSafeHtml().toString()));` - if so what is it?!? How should I be adding a simple `<h1>` and `<hr/>` in a way that's secure (hence the use of the Safe* objects), efficient, and conforming to recommended practices?

The `HTML` widget has a constructor taking a `SafeHtml` so you don't need to call `toString()`.
If you're only using a constant, you don't need a `SafeHtmlBuilder`; use `SafeHtmlUtils` instead. But constants are no more or less *secure* with or without `SafeHtml`, `SafeHtml` just makes it easier to find all occurrences of HTML in your code, to help in doing a security review of your app (BTW, we're doing HTML, so `<hr>`, not `<hr/>`; if you really want it to look like XML/XHTML, then use `<hr />` but you're only [cheating yourself](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml) here)

> Should I be implementing `UiBinder` here? If so, would I make `UiBinder`s for each menu's content or for the entire `mainPanel`, or both?

If you don't feel the need for UiBinder, you don't have to use it. But in this case it won't change anything: you're not handling widget events, but history events.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer (+1) - I'm actually interested in using Activities/Places. So I guess the right question to ask is: **How would I make the hyperlink trigger *navigation*, such as firing a new `PlaceChangeRequest`?**

Comment: Don't use an `Hyperlink` then, use an `Anchor` (use your `PlaceHistoryMapper` to generate the `setHref` value) and a `ClickHandler` that calls `PlaceController#goTo` (don't forget to `event.preventDefault()` too). Well, technically you could use a `Hyperlink` too, but then if the user cancels navigation (in case your activity returns a non-null value from `mayStop`), then the URL would have changed already, contrary to `PlaceController#goTo`.

Answer (score 0):

I have one simple piece of advice to give you. Use what the framework has to offer.

The HTML widget should be your last escape. There are so many widgets that there is no need for you to write html almost anywhere in your code.

So instead of headerBuilder, you can user the following piece of code

```
Label header = new Label("MyWebApp");
header.setStyleName("headerStyle",true);
```

You can set the style properties in an external Css file and add the reference inside the base html file or the gwt.xml file. So that answers your question about  `mainPanel.add(new HTML(headerBuilder.toSafeHtml().toString()));`

In respect to the Hyperlink. If you choose to use hyperlinks, remember that the most effective usage is with the MVP pattern better known as Places and Activities (Lots of information on the web)

If you want something simpler instead the `MenuBar` and `MenuItem` classes should do the trick.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624218/how-do-i-know-that-which-menu-item-is-clicked) for an example on how to use the MenuBar to control your application. There are many other ways but why not use the tools provided?

Also the UIBinder Vs the Designer/Classes methods is extensively discussed on stackoverflow resulting to a matter of choice and programming familiarity/preference.

Comment: Thanks @Thanos K. (+1) - I'm still a little fuzzy/confused though: (1) The JavaDocs for `Label` say that it's meant to be used with conent that is **not** meant to be interpreted as HTML. So how does that work with my desire to use `<h1>` and `<hr>` tags? (2) If the UiBinder "framework" (the XML, annotations, types, etc.) is really just an *alternative* to the "standard" framework as I'm using it above, does it offer any performance/security/efficiency benefits, or is just just for people who are HTML-oriented? I ask because I come from a Swing background so the UiBinder framework...

Comment: (continued from above) ...is actually more difficult for me to understand than Widgets/Panels/POJOs. I don't want to use UiBinder unless there is a good reason, such as performance or security. Thanks again!

Comment: I think that what the javadoc says is that you should not write HTML inside of the Label just what you want it to show. As for the UI Binder it is a bit faster, and the latest GWT Designer supports it so you need not learn a lot of stuff if you are using Eclipse. It also seperates in a more clear way the View from the Presenter and the Model. I personally never use html tags inside the View save for the occassions when I want to use and make custom Cells

Comment: Ahhh, so to clarify: you're saying that it is "normal" in GWT-land to rarely code-in HTML tags like H1 and HR tags...you're saying that GWT provides Widgets that abstract all of that, and that I should either use the Widget library, or go with UiBinder? If so, then as a former Swing developer my philosophy might be: **use Widgets API unless you need something that Widgets doesn't provide. Then, and only then, use UiBinder.** Does that sound like a *decent* game plan?

Comment: I know these questions are vague/subjective, but I'm coding all alone here and I can't think of a better community to ask these "am-i-doin-it-rite?"-type questions. Thanks again.

Comment: The Widgets API and the UiBinder offer more or less (Not sure but this answer might be exactly the same) the same Widget/Functionalities. So yes that would be a safe road to take. And the above is also true. Html is abstracted from GWT. It is generated (and the corresponding javascript) on the client side based on the java you write. THAT is the power of GWT. That is how you can debug java code on the client side. Writing HTML is less safe than using Widgets even if the result is somewhat slower. For me that's the Gain/Loss factor of the framework. UIBinder VS Widget classes is only preference